# class method '+configureWithApplicationID:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Tags: ios, theos

I’m having this problem and it has been the entire day, I couldn’t fix it.
I’m using theos on iphone.

https://imageshack.com/a/img921/3885/bo58U3.png

https://imageshack.com/a/img922/3769/Ooasap.png

```
Tweak.xm:26:15: error: class method '+configureWithApplicationID:' not found (return type defaults to 'id') [-Werror,-Wobjc-method-access]                                
[GADMobileAds configureWithApplicationID:@"ca-app-pub-4010160331162709~1818234899"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Theos, but did you try adding `@import GoogleMobileAds;` at the top for your file? Also, did you check which version of the SDK are you using? The `+[GADMobileAds configureWithApplicationID:]` method was added in version 7.9.0, as stated [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rel-notes).

Comment: Can’t import frameworks in tweak.xm first one can’t be done. I’m using latest version. I tried adding + , even I tried + (id)